# Install messaging tablet app on non-network phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, verizon, instant-messaging

I've got a regular cell phone through Verizon. In addition, I also have a Galaxy Tab and a Galaxy S3, both of those using Wi-Fi only.

I use [Verizon's messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.verizon.messaging.vzmsgs&hl=en) on my regular phone as the default SMS app, and I have the tablet version on my Galaxy tab, which works fine - everything synchronizes, and I can send and receive SMS/MMS messages from the Tab over Wi-Fi.

I'm trying to do the same for the Galaxy S3, but it seems that the phone version of the app only works on a regular network phone - and since my S3 doesn't have a SIM, the app doesn't function.

Is it possible to install make my S3 install the tablet version of the app so this would work? Maybe some way to identify itself as a tablet instead of a phone? Or any other way that you know of to use Verizon Messages from a non-network phone over Wi-Fi?

Comment: You could potentially get the APK off the Tab and install it on the S3.

Comment: Thanks. It was worth a shot, but didn't work. I pulled the apk from my tab to my s3, installed, and it still was the same phone version of the app, and still wouldn't connect.

Comment: The app probably checks the device properties to figure whether it's a tab or a phone, and reacts accordingly. If so, you're screwed. Only thing you could do then is to contact the developers to ask for advice.